# How to get all the sub categories irrespective of their parent categories in wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, categories

As for Example say i have two categories "abc" and "xyz" under this two categories there are several categories. I need to fetch all the sub categories from all the categories.

The categories are dynamic means it may increase i have shown with two.
Is there any functions for wordpress defined already? I couldn't find any can anyone help me with the code??

Thanks
Rahul

Comment: There is no function in WordPress to do this. The best solution that I have found is [here](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/58814/get-second-level-terms-of-custom-taxonomy).

Answer (score 0):

Maybe [get_categories()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_categories) will help ya!

Something like this:

```
$categories = get_categories();
```

Comment: get_categories(), with a parent id returns the childs of that particular parent. I need all the child of different parent.

Comment: @Rahul - If you don't pass any parameters if will bring you all the categories, including all the childrens

Comment: Yupe you are correct. But i don't want the parent category in my array. Can you please help me there?